# I don't want to 'unwrap' an NSNumber - Swift

Tags: swift

What an utter nightmare this portion of Swift seems to be...

```
    let priceNumber = dictionary[kSomeKey] as? NSNumber

    cell.titleLabel.text = String(format: "The price is £%li",priceNumber?.longValue)
```

Compile error: *value of optional NSNumber not unwrapped*

Now, forgive me for potentially being a complete cretin, but I just want my old Obj-C style if nil, display 0... what on earth is going on? if this dictionary key is nil, putting the suggested (priceNumber?.longValue)! will crash right?

Comment: nil is not zero, nil is nothing

Comment: Even if that's the case, I want the logic to be, let it slide... if nil let it print nil.. I don't want to get too bogged down in the semantics. If it printed £(nil) I'd be happy with that. but also, the longValue of nil is 0

Comment: That is defeating the purpose of the optional, which objective c does not have to begin with (objects that can go nil are a little different then what optionals are)  If you want nil to be 0, then you will have to wrap it in something like priceNumber = (priceNumber == nil) ? 0 : priceNumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closest approach

```
let priceNumber = dictionary[kSomeKey] as Int? ?? 0
cell.titleLabel.text = "The price is £\(priceNumber)"
```

The nil coalescing operator `??` unwraps the optional if it's not nil

Comment: Did you mean  as? Int ?? 0 I'll admit this is the first time I've seen \(priceNumber) which looks like a godsend. As is ??.... Amazing thanks.

Comment: Obj-C habits die hard

Comment: Actually yes, but that syntax doesn't work with `??`

Comment: My compiler seems happy with `let priceNumber = dictionary[kSomeKey] as? Int ?? 0`

Comment: `\(priceNumber)`  –  with the backslash  – is just the string interpolation syntax. If the compiler is happy, use it. The compiler complains in a playground.

Comment: @Magoo AnyObject can represent instance of any class type and is not convertible to "Int?" from there you require a downcast optional.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try this way:

%li is expecting a long integer.

In Swift nil is not the equivalent of zero like it might happen in some cases in Obj-C. Nil is **nothing**

Since %li is expecting a long integer, and nil is not literal convertible, and Swift is statically typed, you have to unwrap the number and make sure it is not nil (Zero is not nil).

This might not be the 100% exact technical explanation. But it should give the rough idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it more difficult than it has to be. Values in dictionaries are optional because you might not get a value for a particular key. To be safe, you bind the value from the dictionary in an if let to make sure you actually have an object, then use string interpolation to set the cell's text property.

```
// This is all so you can test it in a playground
var dictionary = [String : AnyObject]()
let kSomeKey = "price"
dictionary[kSomeKey] = NSNumber(long: 12)

// Bind the value out of the dictionary
if let priceNumber = dictionary[kSomeKey] as? NSNumber {
    // priceNumber is guaranteed to be an instance of NSNumber at this point
    cell.titleLabel.text = "The price is £\(priceNumber)")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I simplified the logic to make my point. An massive block of if lets is something I want to avoid.